# this patent is only an idea, how can this qualify for patent protection?

Tags: us9317627

there is nothing specific, application or product behind it and only describes generic use of a formula. the whole patent boils down to an idea of using math to do something on a computer that the math inherently does.

how can this qualify for patent protection when by law ideas and math is not patentable?

In reference to the patent: [US9317627](https://www.google.com/patents/US9317627)

Answer (score 1):

I won't comment on the validity of the patent in question,  but my reading of the first claim suggests it isn't patenting an equation by itself, but the application of the equation to generation computer rendered scenery and video. You can get patents on the specific application of algorithms. I am not a lawyer, merely an inventor with such patents.